# Finding Intersection of Three Circles Given Difference of Radii

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, circles

I have the equations of three circles:

$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

$$(x-1.3)^2 + y^2 = (r+m)^2$$

$$x^2 + (y+1.3)^2 = (r+n)^2$$

Where $n$ and $m$ are values that are calculated and will be replaced.

Using these equations, how can I find the point at which the circles are closest to intersecting (they might not have an exact intersection).

Any help or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Suppose that $r = 1$, and both $m$ and $n$ are $-0.9$. Then you've got a unit circle at the origin, a tiny circle around $(-1.3, 0)$, and a tiny circle around $(1.3, 0)$. I have no idea what "the point at which the circles are closest to intersecting" would be in this case. If we assume it's not the origin, then by symmetry around the $x$ and $y$ axes, the point isn't unique, so "**the** point" doesn't really make sense. I think maybe you need to think through  5 or  6 good examples before refining your question so that it has obvious answers, at least in simple cases

Comment: The circles have centers at (0, 0), (1.3, 0), and (0, -1.3). I believe you mistook the center of the third circle to be (-1.3, 0). Does that resolve the issue with the problem?

Comment: Do you know the concept of power of a point with respect to a circle, for example with respect to the first circle : $Pow((x,y),C_1)=x^2 + y^2 - r^2$ ? It makes sense (in the least square sense) to look for the point $(x,y)$ minimizing the sum of the squares of the three "powers".

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I guess I need more coffee before commenting. But "closest to intersecting" still remains a pretty under-defined notion. Jean Marie has one proposal, but is it what you want? And if it *is* what you want, is it unique?

Comment: Jean Marie's idea looks to be what I want. Thank you for the idea! I'll do some more research to determine if is works with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract the first equation from the second one to get

$$ a^2 - 2 a x = m ^2 +2 m r $$

where $a = 1.3$.

The above gives us the $y$ coordinate of the two possible intersection points between the 1st and 3rd circle.

$$ x_{1,2} = \frac{ a^2 - 2 n r - n^2 }{2 a} $$

The two possible $x$ coordinates of the intersection points are

$$ y_{1,2} = \pm \sqrt{r^2 - x_{1,2}^2} $$

Now subtract the 1st equation from the 3rd equation to get

$$ b^2 - 2 b y = n^2 + 2 n r $$

where $b=-1.3$.

The above gives us the $y$ coordinate of the two possible intersection points between the 1st and 2nd circle.

$$ y_{3,4} = \frac{ b^2 - 2 m r - m^2 }{2 b} $$

The two possible $x$ coordinates of the intersection points are

$$ x_{3,4} = \pm \sqrt{r^2 - y_{3,4}^2} $$

Similarly, subtract the 2nd equation from the 3rd equation to get the equation of the line that connects the two intersection points.

$$2 a x -2 b y -a^2+b^2 = -m^2 -2 m r +n^2 + 2 n r$$

and you can use the 2nd equation and the line above to find the coordinates of the final intersection.

Note that some sets of points might not exist, as those circles might not intersect. Now from the possible 3 sets of 2 intersection points (6 points total), you can take an average, or try to find a circle using least squares that will give you a center and an average radius.

At this point the problem is not well defined, as finding a common point between 6 points is most likely not possible.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The idea about averaging the six points of intersection seems like a good idea.